# How can I create multiple Users for a Chat program?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm doing a Chat program with a Server and I want multiple Clients/Users. I can send message from the server to one client and viceversa, but when I open another Client I can't send them the message. My teacher told me that maybe I'm using the same `Thread`, `Socket` and `Binarywriter` but I don't how to do that.
I created the class User that accepts a `Socket`, `Stream`, `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` and I created a list with that class and I add an user every time that the connection is successful.

Comment: Search the internet "chat program c#" there will be tons of results.

Comment: And please try adding the related parts of your server and client codes. That way you get help much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each message that a client sends, pass a token (or username/password) so the server can recognize (and keep a list of known) users.

Keep a list of connections/sockets and register which user is using which socket. This way if a user sends a message you can recognize him by the socket and send the message on wards to the other sockets.